# How to loop only when say yes/continue. My code just keep looping and don't care about boolean I code

Tags: javascript

I need to write code and in the end, the user can choose to continue or stop. But after try and error for many times, I just can't find the solution. It just keep looping.

```
import java.io.*;

public class medicine {
  public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

    boolean choice;

    do {

      int age;
      String answer = null;
      BufferedReader n = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

      System.out.println("Enter Your Name: ");
      String name = n.readLine();

      System.out.println("Enter Your Age: ");
      age = Integer.parseInt(n.readLine());
      System.out.println("Your recomended paracetamol dosage: ");

      if (age < 1) {
        System.out.println("60 - 120 mg");
      } else if ((age >= 1) && (age <= 5)) {
        System.out.println("120 - 240 mg");
      } else if ((age >= 6) && (age <= 12)) {
        System.out.println("240 - 480 mg");
      } else {
        System.out.println("INVALID AGE, PLEASE REFER TO PHARMACY OR DOCTOR NEAR YOU... THANK YOU");
      }

      System.out.println("Do You Want to Continue?");

    } while (choice = true);
  }
}
```

This is the output. Like you can see, it just looping and don't seem to take any input for yes or no.

```
Enter Your Name: 
Nik
Enter Your Age: 
12
Your recomended paracetamol dosage: 
240 - 480 mg
Do You Want to Continue?
Enter Your Name: 
Sarah
Enter Your Age: 
10
Your recomended paracetamol dosage: 
240 - 480 mg
Do You Want to Continue?
Enter Your Name:
```

Comment: you never update the value of `choice`. additionally the `while` condition should be `choice==true` as a single "=" is not a comparator

Answer (score 0):

Try to read input from user after your question "do you want to continue" , something like:

```
String choice= n.next();
boolean continue= choice.equalsIngoreCase("yes") || choice.equalsIngoreCase("yes")
and change the condition to while (continue);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while (choice=true)
```

`=` is an assignment, not a comparison. You are always setting `choice` to `true` here, so the condition is always true, and the loop always continues.

Use `==` instead; or, better, simply use:

```
while (choice)
```

which avoids the possibility of the typo.

However, you will then need to tackle the problem that you don't otherwise set the value of `choice`: I suppose you have just forgotten to read something from the scanner.